# Is the complement of a closed and nowhere dense set a dense set?

Tags: general-topology

1)Suppose A is a closed and nowhere dense subset of X, is $A^c$ dense?

2)Suppose B is open and dense in X, is $B^c$ nowhere dense?

I tried proving both but it was long and messy so I am not sure it is right ... I wonder if there is a quick way to show this...

Also, is it necessary that A is closed or that B is open?

Here is what I did for the moment :

1. A closed --> cl(A) = A , and A is nowhere dense --> $int(cl(A))=int(A)=\emptyset$
   so A contains no open set.
   Take x in X, we want to show x is in $cl(A^c)$:
   Take U open containing x, thus X is not entirely in A so $U\cap A^c$ is not the empty set so x is in $cl(A^c)$ so X=$cl(A)^c$

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

It’s very easy if you know that $D\subseteq X$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $D\cap U\ne\varnothing$ for every non-empty open set $U$ in $X$; if you’ve not yet seen this characterization of denseness, you should definitely try proving it.

Suppose that $A$ is closed and nowhere dense in $X$, and let $U=X\setminus A$. If $V$ is any non-empty open set in $X$, then $V\nsubseteq A$, so $V\cap U\ne\varnothing$. Thus, $U$ intersects every non-empty open set in $X$ and is therefore dense in $X$.

Conversely, if $U$ is a dense open subset of $X$, then $U$ intersects every non-empty open set in $X$, so $\operatorname{int}(X\setminus U)$ must be empty, and $X\setminus U$ is therefore closed and nowhere dense.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is nowhere dense then $A^{c}$ is dense whether or not $A$ is closed. Proof: Suppose $A^{c}$ is not dense. Then there is an open set $U\neq \emptyset$ such that $U\cap A^{c}=\emptyset$ or $U \subseteq A\subseteq \overline A$. This is a contradiction to the fact that $A$ is nowhere dense.

If $B$ is open and dense then $B^{c}$ is closed and contains no interior points. (Why?)
Hence $B^{c}$ is  nowhere dense. But this implicatin fails if $B$ is not open: Take $B=\mathbb Q$.